# How to update the background color of a textbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, input, setinterval

I want to make a text box all in javascript no html (so can use it in the console.log), update background color with setInterval. How can it be done?

This is what I got so far, but does not work.

```
var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("value", color);
document.body.appendChild(x);
var color;
setInterval(function(){if (x.setAttribute("value",color)===color{document.body.style.backgroundColor=color};},100);
```

Comment: Why is it important that you use `setInterval`?

Comment: because variables are static in JS.

Comment: I mean, why a timer, when you can just use an event handler to detect changes. With a timer you get lag, and you also have the timer running constantly event when it does't need to do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution works with timeinterval

```
var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("value", color);
document.body.appendChild(x);
var color = '#FFFFFF';
setInterval(function () {
    color = x.value; // you need to get value of color code 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color // then it work here
    console.log(color);
}, 100);
```

Comment: You could at least tidy up your answer if you are to be the accepted one

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `setInterval` to poll the change, instead use the `keyup` event to detect when the user changes the value:

```
var color = '#FFFFFF';
var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("value", color);
document.body.appendChild(x);

x.onkeyup = function(){
    color = this.value;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
};
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/02keLgfs/)